# How to set progressbar max value other than setting it on the event form load?

Tags: vb.net-2010

im having problem setting the max progressbar value. the program will ask the user how much is the max progressbar value and then the program sets it.

using `ProgressBar1.Maximum = val` dosent seem to work when outside of `Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load`

Help

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

Add a ProgressBar, Textbox, and Button on a new form.

Next, double-click on the Button, and add the following code:

```
Dim pb1max As Int64
pb1max = TextBox1.Text
ProgressBar1.Maximum = CInt(pb1max)
For j As Integer = 1 To pb1max
    ProgressBar1.Value = j
Next
```

Then, at run-time, type for example 100000 into the Textbox, then click the Button.  You are grabbing the integer value from the Textbox (which the user types in), and then setting ProgressBa1.Max = pb1max.  The loop also goes up to the max value, and ProgressBar1.Value is used to set the progress bar level (percent completion).